# Given that $f(x,y,x)$ is a factor of $g(x,y,z)$:

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $f(x,y,z)=(x-z)^2+(x-y)^2+(z-y)^2$

and $g(x,y,z)=(x-z)^n+(x-y)^n+(z-y)^n$

Then prove that if $f(x,y,z)$ is a factor of $g(x,y,z)$, that $n$ is not divisible by 3.

Please no solutions. I'm only looking for a small hint because I haven't made any progress with my solution.

Comment: Try to find non-trivial roots of $f(x,y,z)$ (i.e. different from $x=y=z$) using the third roots of unity.

Comment: How is that related? I mean how is will I find solutions for a 3 variable function like this?

Comment: You don't have to find all the solutions. But if you find one root of $f(x,y,z)$ (possibly by guessing) then you can conclude that it is also a root of $g(x,y,z)$ and this will give you some condition on $n$

Comment: Yes I thought that much but I really need a clue to proceed further.

Comment: Let me think a bit, actually.

Comment: not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I will write a bit more of my hint here as an answer.
Denote $\omega=e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}$ the third root of unity i.e. $\omega^3=1$ and $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$.
Now, note that
$$f(1,\omega,\omega^2)=(\omega^3-\omega)^2+(\omega^2-\omega)^2+(\omega-1)^2=(\omega-1)^2(\omega^2+\omega+1)=0$$

But if you want $f(x,y,z)$ to be a factor of $g(x,y,z)$ then this implies that if for some $x,y,z$ you have $f(x,y,z)=0$ then you must also have $g(x,y,z)=0$.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Tell me one thing, if any two variables are equal then doesn't this hold for all n?

Comment: Sure, but the condition means (or at least I thought it means) that $f(x,y,z)$ is a factor of $g(x,y,z)$ in an algebraic sense (and not just for specific values of $x,y,z$) i.e. there exists a polynomial $P(x,y,z)$ such that $g(x,y,z)=P(x,y,z) \cdot f(x,y,z)$ for all $x,y,z$

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks.